# Using Mockito MockedConstruction throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, mockito

I have a simple class for fetching a URL:

```
public class UrlFetcher {

    private URL url;

    public UrlFetcher(String address) throws IOException {
        url = new URL(address);
    }

    public int getResponseCode() throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        return con.getResponseCode();
    }

}
```

I am experimenting with Mockito inline-mockmaker and MockedConstruction class:

```
    @Test
    public void givenMockedUrl_whenRequestSent_thenHttpOKReceivedSuccessfully() throws IOException {
        try (MockedConstruction<URL> mocked = Mockito.mockConstruction(URL.class, (mock, context) -> {
            
            HttpURLConnection mockConnection = Mockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
            Mockito.when(mockConnection.getResponseCode()).thenReturn(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

            Mockito.when(mock.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockConnection);
            
            
        })) {
            UrlFetcher fetcher = new UrlFetcher("https://www.google.com/");
            assertEquals(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, fetcher.getResponseCode());
        }
        
    }
```

I am trying to mock the url in the constructor, but when I run my test it says:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mypackage/mock/url/UrlFetcher
    at com.mypackage.mock.url.UrlFetcherMockitoUnitTest.givenMockedUrl_whenRequestSent_thenHttpOKReceivedSuccessfully(UrlFetcherMockitoUnitTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.mock.url.UrlFetcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 41 more
```

I don't really understand the error. If I remove the MockedConstruction the NoClassDefFounderror goes away.

I'm using Mockito core 4.4.0 and mockito-incline 4.4.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Either change the first few lines of your code to:

```
@Test
public void givenMockedUrl_whenRequestSent_thenHttpOKReceivedSuccessfully() throws IOException {
    // Add this line below
    UrlFetcher dummy = new UrlFetcher("https://www.google.com/");
    try (MockedConstruction<URL> mocked = Mockito.mockConstruction(URL.class, (mock, context) -> {
```

or don't use ***mockConstruction*** with URL.

**Long answer:** Within the ***mockConstruction*** block, the construction of a URL is being handled by mockito. However, instantiation of UrlFetcher requires the class to be loaded, and that requires.... URL.
You can either force the class to be loaded before the ***mockConstruction*** block, or - better - don't use ***mockConstruction*** with URL at all.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in these past days and, unfortunately, I didn't find any solution for this problem. In my opinion is a bug of the new version of Mockito.

I became really mad about this problem so my suggestion is to change approach and don't mock the URL.class but injecting a local file URL (like file:///C:/Users/<your_repo>/src/test/resources/_temp/file.txt) as input string parameter (the "address" in your case).

Doing that, you don't need to mock the constructor of URL.class and still your test won't do any external connection, effectively remaining a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

No prob.

```
 @Test
    public void test1() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        URL url = Mockito.mock(URL.class);
        HttpURLConnection con = Mockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        
        when(url.openConnection()).thenReturn(con);
        when(con.getResponseCode()).thenReturn(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

        Class<?> fetcherClass = Class.forName("com.example.demo.UrlFetcher");
        Field field = fetcherClass.getDeclaredField("url");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        UrlFetcher fetcher = new UrlFetcher("https://www.google.com/");
        field.set(fetcher, url);
       
        assertEquals(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, fetcher.getResponseCode());
    }
```